# Plot line plot per weekday and week number

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

I have the following data. This represents the number of occurrences in January:

```
date      value    WeekDay WeekNo Year   Month
2018-01-01  214.0   Monday  1    2018    1
2018-01-02  232.0   Tuesday 1    2018    1
2018-01-03  147.0   Wed     1    2018    1
2018-01-04  257.0   Thursd  1    2018    1
2018-01-05  164.0   Friday  1    2018    1
2018-01-06  187.0   Saturd  1    2018    1
2018-01-07  201.0   Sunday  1    2018    1
2018-01-08  141.0   Monday  2    2018    1
2018-01-09  152.0   Tuesday 2    2018    1
2018-01-10  167.0   Wednesd 2    2018    1
2018-01-15  113.0   Monday  3    2018    1
2018-01-16  139.0   Tuesday 3    2018    1
2018-01-17  159.0   Wednesd 3    2018    1
2018-01-18  202.0   Thursd  3    2018    1
2018-01-19  207.0   Friday  3    2018    1
...         ...        ...       ...    ...
```

WeekNo is the number of the week in a year.

My goal is to have a line plot showing the evolution of occurrences, for this particular month, per week number. Therefore, I'd like to have the weekday in the x-axis, the occurrences on the y-axis and different lines, each with a different color, for each week (and a legend with the color that corresponds to each week).

Does anyone have any idea how this could be done? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first reshape your dataframe to a format where the columns are the week number and one row per weekday. Then, use the `plot` pandas method:

```
reshaped = (df
            .assign(date=lambda f: pd.to_datetime(f.date))
            .assign(dayofweek=lambda f: f.date.dt.dayofweek, 
                    dayname=lambda f: f.date.dt.weekday_name)
            .set_index(['dayofweek', 'dayname', 'WeekNo'])
            .value
            .unstack()
            .reset_index(0, drop=True))

print(reshaped)
reshaped.plot(marker='x')
```

```
WeekNo         1      2      3
dayname                       
Monday     214.0  141.0  113.0
Tuesday    232.0  152.0  139.0
Wednesday  147.0  167.0  159.0
Thursday   257.0    NaN  202.0
Friday     164.0    NaN  207.0
Saturday   187.0    NaN    NaN
Sunday     201.0    NaN    NaN
```

[image: plot]